# Boot stuck at “platform INT3515:01: deferred probe pending”

Tags: arch-linux, boot

On my new system, I’ve installed Arch via `archinstall` but the system fails to boot. Using the live USB works fine, but booting from the installed instance gives `platform INT3515:01: deferred probe pending` which persists until the machine is turned off. For context, the lines that appear before that are included in the following excerpt.

```
intel_rapl_msr: PL4 support detected.
intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
platform INT3515:01: deferred probe pending
```

The hardware was put together by me, and has the following specs:

- MSI Pro Z690-A
- Intel Core i5-13600KF
- ADATA XPG Lancer DDR5 (2x 16GB)
- Samsung 970 Evo Plus (1 TB)
- NVidia GTX1060 6GB

I assume the hardware is constructed correctly considering windows boots just fine from a separate drive.

As for what I’ve already tried: I have no idea where to start with this problem as there seems to be no other users reporting the same thing. I have tried installing without the install script, but that yielded the same issue. I should also mention that I am not new to Arch; I’ve been using it on my old system for about 3 years, so I have a decent technical understanding of how things should work.

Edit: Upon further research, it is highly likely that the problem is to do with the motherboard’s USB-C PD. I am still unable to find a solution, but that may help anyone kind enough to help with the issue.

Comment: Apart from asking whether you took proper esd precautions - no, momentarily touching metal does not count - you are running a board which is not long released. You may have to get a bleeding edge kernel.

Comment: @Bib In reference to “esd precautions”, I was grounded via an anti static strap through the housing of the power supply (connected to the mains ground obviously), hence I don’t believe any such damage has been caused. Additionally, the USB-C ports themselves work on Windows 10. Using a bleeding edge kernel isn’t something I particularly want to do but I accept it is my only real option at this stage. Do you have any idea of the timescale for the kernel (not bleeding edge) to support a new motherboard, and should I file some sort of report somewhere to aid in said support?

Comment: Regards esd, sorry, I had to ask, too many people do not bother with such things. I would just download the latest kernel release and test with that. I assume arch has a bleeding edge kernel line.